# System.IO FileNotFoundException:licencia.txt

Tags: maui

/* In Net Maui I am trying to read a TXT file that I have in my Resoruces\Raw structure to print its content on the page. The output is captured in a Label x:Name="tvLicense" declared in License.xaml.
In Net MAUI give me the error: I don't find where. Any help Please? */

```
using System.Text;

namespace NautilusSMS.Pages;

public partial class License : ContentPage
{ 
    public License()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void License_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tvLicense.Text = "";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        try
        {
            using Stream fileStream = await FileSystem.Current.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("licencia.txt");
            using StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream);

            String line = reader.ReadLine();
            sb.Append(line).Append("\n");
            while (line != null)
            {
                line = reader.ReadLine();
                if (line != null)
                {
                    sb.Append(line).Append("\n");
                }
            }
            tvLicense.Text = sb.ToString();
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DisplayAlert("Alerta", ex.ToString(), "Cancel");
        }//End Catch
    }//End Load

}//End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested the code you provided. This error(System.IO FileNotFoundException) was reported because you didn't set your .txt file as a `MauiAsset`.

`FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync`

> Files that were added to the project with the **Build Action** of **MauiAsset** can be opened with this method. .NET MAUI projects will process any file in the *Resources\Raw* folder as a **MauiAsset**.

For more information, you can refer to [File system helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=android#platform-differences) by official.

**Update:**

Right-click the licencia.txt file, and then click **Properties** -> set **Build Action** to **MauiAsset**.

Comment: How can I set this MauiAsset build action, excuse my ignorance but I don't quite understand MAUI

Comment: @Rene I updated the answer, wish it can help you.

Comment: Great look for Build Action in the Add Files Properties and voila there it was MauiAssets. It has worked wonderfully. Thank you very much for your instructions.